# Amazon SES: Creating verified email address without inbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

All,

I've searched for answers and couldn't find a suitable one and hence the question here --

I have couple of internal services running on AWS which need to send outbound 'notification' emails. such as -- ticketing system, nagios etc. These are akin to no-reply@ email addresses. Example: nagios-alert@example.com and jira-notify@example.com

I could verify the entire domain but I prefer verifying specific email addresses for paranoia. It also allows us to manage outbound email addresses so that any of the services or admin do not misconfigure a server to send unapproved or accident emails on the internet.

How do I verify email addresses without an inbox on Amazon SES since verification requires a valid email box. -- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html

I know I could create an inbox, verify and delete the inbox. But looking for any other way that I may have missed or an alternative that AWS SES offers that I don't know.

Comment: You can do individual or domain-wide verification. If you can come up with a third way of verifying control of an email address I'd be interested in how you imagine it working...

Comment: You do not need SES for something like this.... It's over kill.

Comment: @josten: beats setting up a postfix server and having to update, manage, setup HA, cloudwatch and what not?

Comment: @Chida, not really. You can setup a postfix server with HA in ~30 mins; shorter if you have chef. cloudwatch I havent worked with, so cant speak for that. I use SES now, but for high volume emails (75k a day). Which is why I'm saying its overkill.

Answer (score 2):

AWS doesn't offer any other way to verify an individual email except for receiving the email and clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, I'm afraid. There isn't another verification method that you've missed. You'll have to do as you suggest -- create inboxes and then delete them.